# Horizontal <ul> with fixed first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<ul/>` that is set up horizontally, and is contained within a `<div/>` so that when the `<ul/>` overflows, you can scroll the `<div/>` to see the rest. It looks something like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6m2q/1/)

[image: Horizontally scrolling <ul/>]

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>HEADER</li>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <!-- Additional items -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    white-space:nowrap; overflow-x:scroll; width:100%;}
ul {
    list-style-type:none; }
li {
    display:inline-block; }
```

### Is there a way to "fix" the first element of the `<ul/>` in place while scrolling the overflow?

**The first element (with the text `"HEADER"`) should stay in place while the rest of the items scroll.** I realize there may not be an "elegant" solution for this.

I tried just making the `"HEADER"` item a separate element outside of the `<ul/>`, but since I have the `<ul/>` width set to `100%`, it makes the entire `<ul/>` overflow outside the browser window.

I tagged the question with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) because a) I'm already using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) in my application, and b) I think that it might be possible to `$.clone()` the element and "fix" it in place. That may be the answer, but I'm struggling with the specific implementation or whether there is a simpler way to accomplish this.

Comment: If you're not worried about supporting old browsers, li:first-child{position:fixed;left:0} should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, just change/add the following CSS: ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrVPJ/))

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left: 85px;
}

li:first-child {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -85px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The background on the fixed header needs to be set so the scrolled `li`s aren't visible behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to play with position : fixed for a while now, so here is what I came up with for you, you'll obviously need to play around with it more. Also, you can [look at the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PCv4T/19/).

```
<div class="full">
    <div class="topdiv">
        <ul>
            <li class="fix">HEADER</li>
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
            <li>Item4</li>
            <!-- Additional items -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

.full{
    display : block;
    float : left;
    width : 500px;
}
.topdiv {
    width : 200px;
    overflow : auto;
}
ul {
    width : 1000px;
}
li {
    display : block;
    float : left;
    left : 300px;
    margin-left : 50px;
    margin-top : 25px;
}
.fix {
    position : fixed;
    left : 0px;
    margin-left : 0px;
    margin-top : 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be nice but gets hard to move the seccond li

```
li:first-child {
    position:fixed;
    width:80px;
    background-color:white;
```

}

so if it is possible to move the header outside of the ul this is an easyer solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
div {
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
}
li {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
}
span {
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:80px;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:10;
}
</style>


<span>HEADER</span>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>HEADER</li>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>Item3</li>
        <li>Item4</li>
        <li>Item5</li>
        <li>Item6</li>
        <li>Item7</li>
        <li>Item8</li>
        <li>Item9</li>
        <li>Item10</li>
        <li>Item11</li>
        <li>Item12</li>
        <li>Item13</li>
        <li>Item14</li>
        <li>Item15</li>
        <li>Item16</li>
        <li>Item17</li>
        <li>Item18</li>
        <li>Item19</li>
        <li>Item20</li>
        <li>Item21</li>
        <li>Item22</li>
        <li>Item23</li>
        <li>Item24</li>
        <li>Item25</li>
        <li>Item26</li>
        <li>Item27</li>
        <li>Item28</li>
        <li>Item29</li>
        <li>Item30</li>
        <li>Item31</li>
        <li>Item32</li>
        <li>Item33</li>
        <li>Item34</li>
        <li>Item35</li>
        <li>Item36</li>
        <li>Item37</li>
        <li>Item38</li>
        <li>Item39</li>
        <li>Item40</li>
        <li>Item41</li>
        <li>Item42</li>
        <li>Item43</li>
        <li>Item44</li>
        <li>Item45</li>
        <li>Item46</li>
        <li>Item47</li>
        <li>Item48</li>
        <li>Item49</li>
        <li>Item50</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```