# Setting first li element fixed and to have same layout as the none fixed li element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, fixed-header-tables

I have found that the first `<li>` element can be set to `position: fixed;` so that it does not scroll with other elements [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397959/horizontal-ul-with-fixed-first-element). If I do this, the layout of this element will be broken, namely, the second li will overlap with the first.

**Not fixed state**

[image]

**Fixed state**
[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, all elements are moved to the left and no longer pass the corresponding table. How could I achieve that this first element is fixed and positioned correctly?

Here is the code from my example:

```css
div {
 display: block
}
ul {
 display: table
}
li:first-child {
 position: fixed
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div style="-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-webkit-box-direction: normal;overflow: auto;">
    <ul style="-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-webkit-box-direction: normal;box-sizing: inherit;display: table;width: 100%;list-style: none;">
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;box-sizing: inherit;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;box-sizing: inherit;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">Tags</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">Session ID</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">Session Start</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">Session End</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">Provider</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">Stats</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">Actions</span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-row;vertical-align: middle;">
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">lock_open</i>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">efe5158d-f077-4d79-bddb-760559318d9a</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:48:49.929Z">21.1.2020 20:48:49</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><time datetime="2020-01-21T19:49:12.506Z">21.1.2020 20:49:12</time></span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">asdjndfg</span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <span>12 /</span>
                <span>0 /</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
            <span style="-webkit-box-direction: normal;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
                <a><i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>
                <i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i>
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```